# pass data between Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have tried to pass data from one Action to another in the same Controller but it seems this do not work. I get null. How to pass value between controllers?

Action1

```
 ViewData["ProductId"] = productId;
```

Action2

```
var productId = ViewData["ProductId"];//Always Null
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `this.Session["ProductId"]`, but this approach is generally incorrect and leads to difficult-to-maintain code that isn't scalable.  More likely, you should be passing this to your view to render as an input field (for a form), or for generating urls (for links).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `TempData` to share data until the next request.

Comment: Yes, although TempData is usually used for near real-time user communication messages like 'error occurred', or 'saved successfully'.  Passing model id's using this approach reduces the scalability problem, but not the maintainability problem.

Answer (score 0):

how did you call the second action inside first action? If you call

```
RedircectToAction("Acion2").
```

then you can pass the parameter by action property like this:

```
RedirectToAction("Action2", new { productID= ViewBag.ProductId});

public ActionResult Action2(Guid productID)
{
}
```